# android maps V2 fragment in a fragment does not want to inflate

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I have an actionbar with a viewpager.
If I understood it correctly, I had to create fragments for each tab that will be clicked in my actionbar.
For this I created xml layout files and classes that inherit from Fragment. In the `onCreateView` of these classes I return `inflater.inflate(xml_layout, container, false)`.
Everyting works fine, but my problem is as follows.

Now I want one of these fragment to be a layout that contains a maps V2 fragment.

Actually I want my fragment to look like the following xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_mappart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/grey" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_heading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/map_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_layout_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" >

    <View 
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape_yellow"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="175dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Now, when I create a class that extends from Fragment and inflates this xml, it gives me an error on the xml line where my fragment for maps V2 starts.

I would like to say that when I extend from SupportMapFragment and return `super.onCreateView()` in his own onCreateView, everything works fine, but then I do not have any control of the layout around the map. I want the map to be nested into my own specific layout. So, I'm almost sure that everyting is set up to displat maps V2, but the problem really is that I cannot inflate a fragment to a fragment.

I hope I explained it well enough, and many many thanks if someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't *nest* fragments, which is what you are trying to do here. It would be a convenient feature that I could have used in my own app, and it can be complex to get around this limitation.

It is possible for a fragment within one view to instantiate a fragment in a different view within the same parent hierarchy, but it can't instantiate a fragment within it's own view hierarchy.

There are a number of ways to do what you want to do; you will just have to think about your design.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.
It is weird that it works, but when i click the tab with the map fragment for a second time, then it gives errors. The first time the map fragment gets displayed, it works.

Could you please give an example of one way to do what I want to do, because for the moment, I cannot think of one...

Comment: This is the first time that I'm working with action bar with tabs. All the documentation I found explains how to do this with fragments. But maybe you know how to do the same, without using fragments? Thanks